# Getting data from another form without reloading the first form

Tags: c#

I'm new to .net.

I'm now just developing a simple application of patient record.First form is `Appointments`(Which is a MDI child form for the Home form).

First i will enter the name and when i click a button for patient code it will show the form of `patientrecord`. In this form i will enter the patient personal details and then if i click the save button, the Tokenno textbox  of Appointments form should be increased by 1.

but when i close the `Patientrecord` form, the name textbox is getting clear. and also token no is not getting increased. Can u please help how to update the `Appointments` form without reloading it from the 'patientrecord' form.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [FAQ] and [ask] before start asking questions..

Comment: I remember that I'he answered questions like this not only once, but possibly I've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a class "Global" in your project "WinForm" and add the attributes to be reachable from all pages and retain their value even if the "reload"

Small example of global class:

```
public static class global
{
    /* ************************************ */
    // Variables Global
    /* ************************************ */
    public static firstName;
    public static lastName;
    public static birthday;
    public static email;
    //etc....
}
```